# Pandas dataframe - column with list of dictionaries, extract values and convert to comma separated values

Tags: pandas

I have the following dataframe that I want to extract each numerical value from the list of dictionaries and keep in the same column.
for instance for the first row I would want to see in the **data** column: `179386782, 18017252, 123452`

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | [{'id': '179386782'}, {'id': 18017252}, {'id': 123452}] |

below is my code to create the dataframe above ( I've hardcoded `stories_data` as an example)

```
for business_account in data:
    business_account_id = business_account[0]
    stories_data = {'data': [{'id': '179386782'}, {'id': '18017252'}, {'id': '123452'}]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(stories_data.items())
    df.set_index(0, inplace=True)
    df = df.transpose()
    df_stories['id'] = business_account_id
    col = df_stories.pop("id")
    df_stories.insert(0, col.name, col)
```

I've tried this:  `df_stories["data"].str[0`]

but this only returns the first element (dictionary) in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df['data'] = df['data'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join([str(d['id']) for d in x]))
print(df)

# Output:
      id                         data
0  12345  179386782, 18017252, 123452
```

Another way:

```
df['data'] = df['data'].explode().str['id'].astype(str) \
                       .groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join)
print(df)

# Output:
      id                         data
0  12345  179386782, 18017252, 123452
```

Comment: thanks! for the first way you mentioned, what does this part do? str(d['id'])

Comment: As your values are numbers, I have to cast them to string to join them.